# ASP.NET MVC Deployment on IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6

I'm just a beginner about ASP.NET MVC. Thought it doesn't have any problems in the developing time, I don't even know what to continue when I try to deploy. After deployment, I can only browse login page.

I'm using

- Windows Server 2003
- IIS 6.0
- Visual Studio 2008

Is there any step by step guide that will be suit for beginner like me?
Anybody can show me any light upon it, please?

Waiyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS6 will not natively support the MVC routing architecture. Phil Haack has a good article about getting this up and running:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You will need to either map all requests through aspnet_isapi.dll, or use an extension on your URLs like ".mvc" for the routing to work properly through IIS 6. See here:

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

There are also a bunch of questions on SO covering this, so this question is probably a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have any deployment issue. Take a look at [ASP.NET MVC and  Model-view-controller pattern - where do I start from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599/asp-net-model-view-controller-mvc-where-do-i-start-from)